# Getting easy-menu to display a submenu

Tags: backquote, easy-menu

I am using easy-menu but cannot get the submenu to work

```
(defvar mcp-outl-subm
  '("Outl"
      ["Hide Direct Body" outline-hide-entry
         :help "Hide Entry"]
      ["Expose Direct Body" outline-show-entry
         :help "Show Entry"]
      ["Expose Headings" outline-hide-body
         :help "Hide Body"])
  "Sub-Menu for outline tools.")

  (easy-menu-define emenu global-map "Emenu"
    '("Emenu"
        ["Outl"  mcp-outl-subm  t]))
```

Checked out the backquote thing without solving the problem

```
  (easy-menu-define emenu global-map "Emenu"
    `("Emenu"
        ["Outl"  ,mcp-outl-subm  t]))
```

Comment: You can answer this question yourself after reading https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html , you don't need us for this. I promise the manual will tell you *exactly* what you need, *with examples*. 

When you have made the simple change you need (two characters), you can post your own answer and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I checked it out but did not work.  Which functions in the list should I evaluate, this one `,mcp-outl-subm`.

Comment: What did not work? Please share an example. It is very hard to help you if you do not show us the path you are following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```el
  (easy-menu-define emenu global-map "Emenu"
    `("Emenu"
       ,mcp-outl-subm))
```