# Reusing a code block to define a sub-menu with easy-menu-define

Tags: eval-expression, easy-menu

I'm trying to reuse a code block to define a sub-menu to be used in different parts (minor mode menus) of my code. I've attempted to define a variable to hold the sub-menu code block and then use it in my menu definitions, but it seems there's an issue with the syntax or variable usage.

This is a MWE:

```el
(defun function-a ()
  (interactive)
  (message "a"))

(defun function-b ()
  (interactive)
  (message "b"))

(defun function-c ()
  (interactive)
  (message "c"))
  
(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE "
                              'face '(:foreground "RoyalBlue" :background "DarkGoldenrod1")))

  :keymap
  `(
    (,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . mwe-function)
    )

  (if mwe-mode
        (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
          "MWE"
          '("MWE mode"
            ;; I want the menu on mode-line only:
            :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))

            ("Functions"
             ["function-a" function-a
              :help "Prints a"]
             ["function-b" function-b
              :help "Prints b"]
             ["function-c" function-c
              :help "Prints c"])
            
            ))

    t))
```

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```el
(defvar functions-submenu
  '("Functions"
    ["function-a" function-a
     :help "Prints a"]
    ["function-b" function-b
     :help "Prints b"]
    ["function-c" function-c
     :help "Prints c"])
  "Docstring")

(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE "
                              'face '(:foreground "RoyalBlue" :background "DarkGoldenrod1")))

  :keymap
  `(
    (,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . mwe-function)
    )

  (if mwe-mode
        (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
          "MWE"
          '("MWE mode"
            ;; I want the menu on mode-line only:
            :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))

        EVALUATION OF MY VARIABLE (FUNCTION?) HERE
            ;; ("Functions"
            ;;  ["function-a" function-a
            ;;   :help "Prints a"]
            ;;  ["function-b" function-b
            ;;   :help "Prints b"]
            ;;  ["function-c" function-c
            ;;   :help "Prints c"])
            
            ))

    t))
```

I know that a "submenu" must be a list with a precise format but I don't know how to store it in a variable and how to use it in the `easy-menu-define` definition.

Comment: ... and the error is? Please include error messages in the question where applicable.

Comment: @NickD I added the error I get.

Comment: @Nick I found that my question is a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/78007/15606, solved by you. Your answer there, solves my question too. I flagged my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for finding it and for marking your question as duplicate! I vaguely remembered that I had done some research on that but I didn't remember the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my question is a duplicate of [Getting easy-menu to display a submenu](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/78007/15606).

NickD's answer there, solves my question too.

Here's my working code:

```el
(defun function-a ()
  (interactive)
  (message "a"))

(defun function-b ()
  (interactive)
  (message "b"))

(defun function-c ()
  (interactive)
  (message "c"))

(defvar functions-submenu
  '("Functions"
    ["function-a" function-a
     :help "Prints a"]
    ["function-b" function-b
     :help "Prints b"]
    ["function-c" function-c
     :help "Prints c"])
  "Docstring")

(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE "
                              'face '(:foreground "RoyalBlue" :background "DarkGoldenrod1")))

  :keymap
  `(
    (,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . mwe-function)
    )

  (if mwe-mode
        (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
          "MWE"
          `("MWE mode"
            ;; I want the menu on mode-line only:
            :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))

            ;; ("Functions"
            ;;  ["function-a" function-a
            ;;   :help "Prints a"]
            ;;  ["function-b" function-b
            ;;   :help "Prints b"]
            ;;  ["function-c" function-c
            ;;   :help "Prints c"])

            ,functions-submenu

            ))

    t))
```